# Converting "ALOS PALSAR" DEM to EGM96 vertical system using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, convert, srtm

I have downloaded "ALOS PALSAR" DEM from [NASA's EOSDIS](https://search.asf.alaska.edu/#/?flightDirs=&zoom=9&center=48.55568297735884,28.689347530449965&polygon=POLYGON((48.1778%2029.2768,48.5596%2029.2768,48.5596%2029.5376,48.1778%2029.5376,48.1778%2029.2768))&dataset=ALOS&subtypes=ALOS$$&productTypes=ALOS$$RTC_HI_RES&beamModes=ALOS$$&polarizations=ALOS$$&resultsLoaded=true&granule=ALPSRP104550570-RTC_HI_RES).

Can you help me to convert the high-res DEM to EGM96 (like SRTM data)?

I have used ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 edition but it does not work correctly.

I have checked the vertical box to enable vertical transformation:

[image]

Now the sea level is 200 meter and other elevations are 140 meter or something similar instead of being 1 meter or 2 meter!

I have tried many times now I'm here!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/343899/115  As a new user please take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all new users to this site and its protocols.

Comment: Actually these are similar but these are two different questions :)

Comment: Then to avoid anyone inadvertently making them duplicates please take care to edit each so that they are asking different questions as clearly as possible.